# Парс JSON объектов Swift в список

Tags: json, swift

У меня есть jsoт полученный из URL,
Data =
  {
    "fName": "Chris",
    "country": "China",
  },
  {
    "fName": "Kate",
    "country": "Canada",
  },
  {
    "fName": "John",
    "country": "USA",
  }
Мне очень хочется сохранить его в список и сделать источником для пикера.

Для этого я создаю:

private let people: [String:String]

И пишу функцию для парса:

```
private func parseCompaniesList(data: Data) {
    do {
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        let peopleObjects = json["url"] as? String

        guard
            let json = jsonObject as? [String: Any],
            let fName = json["fName"] as? String,
            let country = json["country"] as? String,


            else {
                print("! Invalid JSON format")
                return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.people = (?)

        }
    } catch {
        print("! JSON parsing error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

нет конечного понимания как из json создать список.
за помощь заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

update:

```
private func parseCompaniesList(data: Data) -> [String: String] {
    var newArray = [String: String]()
    do {
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        guard
            let array = jsonObject as? [[String: Any]]
            else {
                print("! Invalid JSON format")
                return newArray
        }

        for i in 0..<array.count {
            newArray[array[i]["fName"] as! String] = array[i]["country"] as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("! JSON parsing error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Подскажите пожалуйста еще - как тогда использовать получившийся массив(?) для дата пикера. У меня был хардкод вида:
 private let companies: [String:String] = [
        "John": "USA",
        "Kate": "Canada",
        "Chris": "China"]

        return self.companies.keys.count
        return Array(self.companies.keys)[row]
        let selectedName = Array(self.companies.values)[selectedRow]

Comment: См. update. Переписал код функции, чтобы Вам не ломать код пикера. Сейчас функция возвращает массив в Вашем формате, используйте его для пикера.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам, Олег, очень помогли

Comment: Пожалуйста, Елена :)